# Is there a way to tell JPA/Hibernate to transform column names from camcel case to _'s?

Tags: hibernate, rename

Is there a generic way to tell JPA/Hibernate to transform all column names of the form:

emailAddress

to the form:

email_address

?

I'd rather not have to use a @Column annotation for hundreds of columns. I hope someone thought of this ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [Hibernate Reference Documenation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-namingstrategy) -  3.6. Implementing a NamingStrategy

> The interface
>   org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy
>   allows you to specify a "naming
>   standard" for database objects and
>   schema elements.
>
> You can provide rules for
>   automatically generating database
>   identifiers from Java identifiers or
>   for processing "logical" column and
>   table names given in the mapping file
>   into "physical" table and column
>   names. This feature helps reduce the
>   verbosity of the mapping document,
>   eliminating repetitive noise (TBL_
>   prefixes, for example). The default
>   strategy used by Hibernate is quite
>   minimal. You can specify a different
>   strategy by calling 
>   Configuration.setNamingStrategy()
>   before adding mappings: ...

See also: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19838.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried this, but it doesn't work with JPA. I put println statements to see if the naming strategy is getting called... and it doesn't. And yes, in the persistence.xml, I am setting hibernate's naming strategy property to the custom implementation of naming strategy :(

Comment: Nevermind, the real problem was that I needed to use "hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" instead of "hibernate.naming.strategy". Grrrr. Thanks